# How to create an inverted PWM on the Due via software

Tags: pwm, arduino-due

Hello I am i need of a piece of code that lets me invert a PWM signal of two PWM pins on the due. Example D1 will be 101010 and D2 will be 010101. Is it possible?

Im pretty limited in my options because, doing it externally is not an option because there will be a time where a change in mode is needed and both pins will be sending signal independently. Manually pulling the pins High and Low is also not an option for me because this will make the code blocking other codes.

Comment: inverted 75% is same as noninverted 25%

Comment: @jsotola i am having trouble visualizing that, although they would be opposing but the frequency would not match, the 25% would miss one cycle of the 75% . Am i missing something?

Comment: take a piece of paper and a pencil ... dreaw 10 cycles of 25% PWM waveform ... rotate the paper upside down ... maybe I'm missing something

Comment: [Image](https://ibb.co/mbfz7Sf). The above signal in the image is 75% and the one at the bottom is 25%. the 25% is missing one cycle of the 75%

Comment: this is PWM ... https://www.nightsea.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/PWM-diagram.jpg

Comment: Yeah i got a wrong understanding of pwm, im sorry. [New Image](https://ibb.co/JrWhh7X) although inverted but i have to phase out by a little bit. Now that would be a different approach, i guess which ever is easier to do, both i think would involve direct register manipulations

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103672/discussion-between-jsotola-and-jack).

Comment: you could use an xor gate to invert the PWM signal. this allows you to   easily un-invert the signal with another GPIO pin feeding the gate's other input.

Comment: @dandavis well that is an approach i can go if i cant find a way to do in via software.  with everything i have read so far, I believe that it can be done via software, getting there is ust a little bit difficult

Answer (score 1):

Not using the Arduino API, no. But you can by direct manipulation of the SAM3X8E registers.

You should study section 38 of [the datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-11057-32-bit-Cortex-M3-Microcontroller-SAM3X-SAM3A_Datasheet.pdf), where it mentions in the list of facilities:

> - Independent Complementary Outputs with 12-bit Dead-Time Generator (Also Called Dead-Band or Non-Overlapping Time) for Each Channel

Comment: Register manipulation is way over me, hopefully there is some examples.

Comment: @Jack There probably are, but probably not around here. The Atmel forums might be good though.